# Button to select check boxes based on start of string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form that has users listed and each user has checkboxes below their names.  I want to have a button for each user that selects all of that users checkboxes.

Here's the dynamically created button code and the dynamically created checkboxes.  The function included has the form name, start of the checkbox IDs, and checkbox value as arguments.

```
<input type="button" onclick="SetAllCheckBoxes('form1', '<? echo $row['ID']; ?>_', true);" value="Check All">

<input name="<? echo $userID?>_<? echo $checkboxNumber ?>" type="checkbox" id="<? echo $userID?>_<? echo $checkboxNumber  ?>" value="1" />
```

I need the onclick function that will click all of the desired users checkboxes when clicked.  I think I'll need some form of regular expression somewhere to select for example: All of the checkboxes that start with 12_ or 15_

Comment: please provide more information regarding your script and markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the button a name that is the user ID part of the checkbox names, you could do:

```
<button type="button" name="userFoo" onclick="setCheckboxes(this)" ...>Check 'em</button>
```

Then in the function:

```
function setCheckboxes(element) {
  var re = new RegExp('^' + element.name + '_');
  var controls = element.form.elements;

  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (re.test(controls[i].name)) {
      controls[i].checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Some test HTML:

```
<form>
  <button name="foo" type="button" onclick="setCheckboxes(this)">Check 'em</button>
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo_1">1
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo_2">2
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo_3">3
  <br>
  <button name="bar" type="button" onclick="setCheckboxes(this)">Check 'em</button>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bar_1">1
  <input type="checkbox" name="bar_2">2
  <input type="checkbox" name="bar_3">3
</form>
```

If you were to put a class on each of the checkboxes that is the user ID, then the function might be:

```
function setCheckboxes(element) {
  var controls = element.form.querySelectorAll('input.' + element.name);
  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    controls[i].checked = true;
  }
}
```

or in modern browsers (but not IE8):

```
function setCheckboxes(element) {
  var controls = element.form.querySelectorAll('input.' + element.name);
  [].forEach.call(controls, function(el){el.checked = true});
}
```